# Problems with cyrillic

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, internationalization

I have feature class settlement in my geodatabase and i have two attributes for them. Name on latin and name on cyrillic. When I use same feature to another computer (export feature class) i cannot see cyrillic letters in tabel, and can't label it. On both computer I have arcgis version 10.0. Do i need some additional settings on second computer?

Comment: You might want to check if the relevant font is installed on that other computer (Control panel --> Appearance and personalization --> Fonts).

Answer (score 1):

Problem is most probably with computer or database, not ArcGIS. Check regional setting in control panel( for example: default language for non unicode ) and geodatabase collation properties. Problem must be in one of them.